# Rails 4 Javascript files not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, erb

Hello i have some problem with including javascript files to my rails app.

I'm using rails 4

first i write to these files names to my application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require CanvasRenderer
//= require Projector
//= require three.min
//= require me
//= require_tree .
```

they are have on my **vendor/assets/javascripts** too. So when i open my page from browser nothing working

i look to page source and can see that, my js files getting from header

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/home.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application.self-e80e8f2318043e8af94dddc2adad5a4f09739a8ebb323b3ab31cd71d45fd9113.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true" />
  <script src="/assets/jquery.self-660adc51e0224b731d29f575a6f1ec167ba08ad06ed5deca4f1e8654c135bf4c.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.self-e87806d0cf4489aeb1bb7288016024e8de67fd18db693fe026fe3907581e53cd.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/turbolinks.self-c37727e9bd6b2735da5c311aa83fead54ed0be6cc8bd9a65309e9c5abe2cbfff.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/CanvasRenderer.self-28076336bdf42eb56ef55649b880be9c4c40f4f9991aaa7cae7ba317c60e57a6.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/Projector.self-b4b1414a2f0bcaf573fcbc6a52ee0a989659089fe0d392f13545f1f065e1abd9.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/three.min.self-9bfe8e307ba0fd9ffeb655fcfc20d5017f34a3d41235b34e06b5fac3da6fd8f1.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/me.self-673e4489da4471935b3097fdd8e29ab07f0bc14dc377bca6dc9cd9cf6e39ec23.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/home.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.self-10ad0916cf31256fe71785e8dc9cc297a96b1cdf7b74aeb61711199b9a3d003f.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
  <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="bs8wy2VKuszAk+pdH1e8cLLsL+P21x0Xm8hY76MoccKCPYiKE+QpGqHHuoWe7lwpvOgVsRW/3pyzf6OqBO23YA==" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
</head>
```

and console log give an error

```
CanvasRenderer.self-28076336bdf42eb56ef55649b880be9c4c40f4f9991aaa7cae7ba317c60e57a6.js:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: THREE is not defined
Projector.self-b4b1414a2f0bcaf573fcbc6a52ee0a989659089fe0d392f13545f1f065e1abd9.js:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: THREE is not defined
me.self-673e448….js?body=1:22 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null
```

the same files i'm using here and everything is okey. 
http://kleaz.com/demo/dev/

i can't understand why

Comment: some times you need to restart your local server

Answer (score 0):

`CanvasRenderer` and `Projector` are trying to use `THREE` before it's been defined in three.min.js.

Changing the asset order in your manifest to the following (also the order used in your example) should solve the problem:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require three.min
//= require CanvasRenderer
//= require Projector
//= require me
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Thanks you, i tried this method. on console i have just one error now : 'me.self-673e448….js?body=1:22 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null'

Comment: container = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(container);